# Android: Shortcut to testing by saving Activity state

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, save

I am using android studio with an emulator. When I change the code, I need to test it. The thing is, sometimes I have to perform a dozen click, fetch data from internet, etc, until I get to the screen I want to.

Is there a way for me to "save" the activity state, and quickly jump back to that activity after having changed the code? That would save me hours of dev.

I'm opened to any other tips that would speed up my testing process

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can Make the Activity you are trying to test as your launching Activity and feed it with seed data that you are trying to fetch from the internet. It will save you a lot of man hours. I would suggest you to go for a TDD approach rather using Robotium where you can test all the functional code of yours.